# on value set function in jquery or javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a sample when you type in input element run a function 
But I need when it change by another function , run a function !
see it and help me :  http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/5kpeJ/

```
$('#modern').bind('input', function() {
$(this).next().stop(true, true).fadeIn(0).html( $(this).val()).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

- when click on button function not Run !

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what you're asking....

Comment: wtf.. use google translator to help u improve your question..

Comment: see link ! when you write the function is runing but when you click button not running ! I want when change input value with another function if run a function

Comment: Changing the value programatically does not trigger the event, you have to manually trigger it with `$('#modern').trigger('input')`

Comment: Are you saying that programmatic changes to the input element do not trigger the associated event handier? (Which is normal.) But you want them to?

Comment: Insted of using this inside this function replace it with the particular functions dom id so that when ever that dom gets change that function will be invoked.

Comment: @nnnnnn I want when change input value with button , run a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this http://jsfiddle.net/5kpeJ/902/ ?
you should create a trigger and run it

```
$("input").focus(function(){
$("<span>Focused!</span>").appendTo("body").fadeOut(1000);
});
```